# How to configure grails 2.4 with AngularJS and not using plugins

Tags: angularjs, grails-2.4

How do I configure a grails2.4 application (asset pipeline) with Angular js. (without using any plugins)

So far, this is what I have and it doesnt seem to work.

I put angular.min.js in the folder `grails-app/assets/javascripts` 
and I did this in the gsp

```
`<asset:javascript src="angular.min.js" />
<asset:javascript src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js" />`
```

and

```
`<html ng-app="VTPaceApp" novalidate>`
```

when I did this `{{ "Your's," + " truly" }}`, I dont see any angular effect.

I've also tried putting `//= require /angular/angular` in application.js and that did not work either.

Thanks.

Comment: where is your `VTPaceApp` function defined?

Comment: in main.js `(function() {
 var app = angular.module('VTPaceApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`   and  I included main.js like this `<asset:javascript src="main.js" />`

Comment: ok, that looks correct; so what are you seeing when you load the page? and are you getting any errors in the browser debug console?  also, please update your question with code elements, they are impossible to read in comments.

Comment: Sorry about that. I dont see any errors on the debug console. Except for a warning.  `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Comment: hmm, tried to load angular more than once? that tells me there is something not right with the scripts and the load order; I think we need to see a more complete picture of the HTML and JavaScript you are working with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to working. Followed this [blog](https://vasya10.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/), 
so, basically, did `bower install angular` 
add these directives to application.js 
 `//= require angular/angular
//= require_tree views` 
add `<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>` to gsp 
Test using the following code in your gsp 
`<div ng-app="">
    <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
    <p> {{"Your are " + " welcome"}}</p> </div>`